# Error mopub plugin

Tags: cordova

I am integrating mopub banner ads for ios. But the dimensions of ads is full height which is blocking the app. I have used cordova plugin add com.rjfun.cordova.mopub for integration.

```
if(MoPub) MoPub.createBanner( {
   adId: adid.banner, 
   position:MoPub.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
   autoShow:true
} );
```

Same is working fine for android.